# Bar Chart jumps up when there's more than 2 columns

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I am working on a chart with data set change when the button is pressed. But it looks like when I have more than 2 bars, the chart origin point shifts.

[image: Chart]

Two columns is fine:

[image: 2 column chart]

**Creating data set:**

```
private func buildMoodDummyBarData(period: Period) -> [BarChartDataEntry] {

    if period == .week {
        let entry1 = BarChartDataEntry(x: 0, y: 720)
        let entry2 = BarChartDataEntry(x: 1, y: 440)
        let entry3 = BarChartDataEntry(x: 2, y: 0)
        let entry4 = BarChartDataEntry(x: 3, y: 30)
        let entry5 = BarChartDataEntry(x: 4, y: 30)

        return [entry1, entry2, entry3, entry4, entry5]

    } else if period == .month {

        let entry1 = BarChartDataEntry(x: 0, y: 100)
        let entry2 = BarChartDataEntry(x: 1, y: 300)
        let entry3 = BarChartDataEntry(x: 2, y: 50)
        let entry4 = BarChartDataEntry(x: 3, y: 30)
        let entry5 = BarChartDataEntry(x: 4, y: 30)

        return [entry1, entry2, entry3, entry4, entry5]

    } else {

        return []
    }
}
```

**Finishing building data set and changing bar colors:**

```
func buildMoodBarData(period: Period) -> BarChartData? {

    let entries = buildMoodDummyBarData(period: period)

    let set = BarChartDataSet(values: entries, label: nil)
    set.highlightEnabled = false

    let tempData = BarChartData(dataSet: set) // Just to find max
    let max = tempData.yMax
    let onePercent = max / 100

    var colors = [UIColor]()
    for item in entries {
        let percentValue = item.y / onePercent
        colors.append(setColor(value: percentValue))
    }
    set.colors = colors

    let data = BarChartData(dataSet: set)
    data.setDrawValues(true)
    data.barWidth = 0.72

    return data
}

// barChartView is storyboard outlet
private  func makeMoodBarChart() {

    barChartView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    barChartView.chartDescription = nil
    barChartView.leftAxis.enabled = false
    barChartView.rightAxis.enabled = false
    barChartView.legend.enabled = false
    barChartView.xAxis.enabled = false
}

private func updateMoodBarChart(with data: BarChartData) {

    barChartView.data = data
    barChartView.fitBars = false
    barChartView.fitScreen()
}
```

Comment: In the scenario with 5 elements, does the positioning also change when switching between periods that have the exact same data in both returned BarChartDataEntry arrays? My guess it's a default, automatic scaling of the y axis that is dependent on the values.

Comment: Position is only shifting when data is different. Yes it does looks like default library behaviour but what an odd decision.

Answer (score 0):

While updating Barchart with new dataset make chartdata as nil

```
if let bardata = buildMoodBarData(period: state) {
    barChatView.data = nil

    updateMoodBarChart(with: bardata)
}
```

Comment: Tried this, didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to data set. When I replaced it to following data, problem disappeared. I think issue occurs because Y scale values was changing too much.

```
private func buildMoodDummyBarData(period: Period) -> [BarChartDataEntry] {

    if period == .week {
        let entry1 = BarChartDataEntry(x: 0, y: 10)
        let entry2 = BarChartDataEntry(x: 1, y: 50)
        let entry3 = BarChartDataEntry(x: 2, y: 100)
        let entry4 = BarChartDataEntry(x: 3, y: 20)
        let entry5 = BarChartDataEntry(x: 4, y: 30)

        return [entry1, entry2, entry3, entry4, entry5]

    } else if period == .month {

        let entry1 = BarChartDataEntry(x: 0, y: 100)
        let entry2 = BarChartDataEntry(x: 1, y: 30)
        let entry3 = BarChartDataEntry(x: 2, y: 30)
        let entry4 = BarChartDataEntry(x: 3, y: 20)
        let entry5 = BarChartDataEntry(x: 4, y: 30)

        return [entry1, entry2, entry3, entry4, entry5]

    } else {

        return []
    }
}
```

This doesn't mean min and max value has to be exactly the same in both data sets (20 to 100), however if difference is too big (30 to 320 in first data set and 30 to 720 in second), chart baseline changes.

This is not ideal solution.